# Insulation tape behind a baseboard heater

Tags: drywall, insulation, winter, tape, duct-tape

In the apartment I am in, there is baseboard heater located under the balcony door

During the winter cold air come through the wall, and from gaps or crack between the wall and the floor

Usually during winder, around windows, I just put duct tape around windows and in any area that leaks cold air (gaps between the wall and floor)

I am thinking to unscrew the heater, put some tape on the drywall for insulation (reduce or block the cold air flow)

What type of tape should I use, that would be effective and safe, should I use regular duct tape or is it better to use foil tape, or something else completely

Comment: "Apartment" implies "rental", so if that's not the case, please correct. Since it's a rental, I'd suggest talking to the landlord about making a quality fix to this situation. It's possible that not only is there an air leak, but that water might also be leaking through this location and that would cost the landlord money to fix water damage.

Comment: I have been in this apartment, for 3 years now, we never had a water leak 
I think some tape should do the job, just needing advice, on best type of tape to use